# Perl regular expression to find a exact word

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find the word `sprintf` in my code. What Perl regular expression should be used?
There are some lines which have text like `sprintf_private`, which I want to exclude, but need just `sprintf`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must use `\b` at the words' border:

```
/\bsprintf\b/
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find all occurrences of `sprintf` on lines that do not contain `sprintf_private`, you might use a pair of regexes:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ m/\bsprintf_private\b/;
    while( $line =~ m/\bsprintf\b/g ) {
        print "[sprintf] found on line $. at column $-[0]\n";
    }
}
```

This first rejects any line containing `sprintf_private`.  Then lines not containing that disqualifier are scanned for all occurrences of `sprintf`.  Wherever it's found, a message is printed identifying the line in the file and the starting column of the match where `sprintf` is found.

The `$.` and `@-` special variables are described in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).  And some good reading on regular expressions can be found in [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  The first regular expression is pretty simple; it just uses the `\b` zero width assertion to assure that the disqualifying substring has a word boundary at each side of it.  The second regex uses that same technique but also applies the `/g` modifier to iterate over all occurrences of `sprintf` just in case there happens to be more than one occurrence per line.

The zero width assertion `\b` matches anywhere that a `\w\W` or `\W\w` transition occurs.  Since the character class `\w` contains all alpha characters (where what constitutes "all" depends on your `unicode_strings` flag, or `/u`), plus underscore and numeric digits (ie, whatever characters are permissible in an identifier), you might find the `\b` word boundary too restrictive.  If you find that the "simple" solution is too naive of an approach, you could go the extra mile and really narrow down what should qualify as a word boundary by using a regex that looks like this:

```
(?<!\p{Alpha})sprintf(?!\p{Alpha})
```

If you chose to go this route, the solution would look like this:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ m/(?<!\p{Alpha})sprintf_private(?!\p{Alpha})/;
    while( $line =~ m/(?<!\p{Alpha})sprintf(?!\p{Alpha})/g ) {
        print "[sprintf] found on line $. at column $-[0]\n";
    }
}
```

This uses zero width negative lookbehind and zero-width negative lookahead assertions that reject matches where the character immediately to the left or right of the primary substring are "Alpha" characters, rather than using the slightly more naive `\b`.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing in what way "This answer is not useful", so that I can either improve it or justify removing it.

Comment: +1 for your very good explanation. I think you might have been downvoted because the question didn't say *find all occurrences of sprintf on lines that do not contain snprint_private*, so this might be considered a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I was concerned a little with the specification.  "*find the word sprintf in my code*" seemed like an implicit "all instances", and "*some lines which have text like sprintf_private, which I want to exclude*", while a little more ambiguous, seemed to me to be saying it's Ok for `sprintf` to appear on those lines, so ignore them.  Anyway, I guess there's nothing technically incorrect, so I'll leave it as it stands for now.

Comment: I did notice that the original question was edited such that `snprint_private` became `sprintf_private`, so I've updated the answer to reflect that change.

Comment: I also see that one could interpret the `sprintf_private` clause to mean that while "sprintf" is of interest, if it is followed by "_private", it's not.  In that case, the first check, "`next if ...`" becomes unnecessary, and the second check should definitely end in a `(?!\p{Alpha})` so that underscore is seen as a transition.